# MySql join by json key and multiply quantity for each order item and get total price

Tags: mysql, json

I could not fiddle this out for hours now.

I would like to have the total price in one sql select.

Given is a json column where the key is the productId and the value is the quantity.

The customer can have multiple order items.

The quantity must be multiplied with net_price and tax_price.
In SUM This gives the total price.

I can do this relational without json, but my preference is a json column.

I prepared an example to make it clear:

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE order_items (
  `customer_id` VARCHAR(26),
  `products` json
);

INSERT INTO order_items VALUES  ('01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KL', '{"01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KH": 10, "01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KK": 20}');
INSERT INTO order_items VALUES  ('01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KL', '{"01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KH": 30}');
INSERT INTO order_items VALUES  ('01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KL', '{"01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KH": 30}');

CREATE TABLE product (
  `productId` VARCHAR(26),
  `net_price` INTEGER,
  `tax_price` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO product VALUES  ('01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KH', 100, 20);
INSERT INTO product VALUES  ('01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KK', 200, 10);
```

What I have by now but it is incomplete:

```
SELECT
    JSON_UNQUOTE(
            JSON_EXTRACT(
                    JSON_KEYS(`products`),
                    CONCAT(
                            '$[',
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `products`) -1,
                            ']'
                        )
                )
        ) AS "productId",quantity
FROM order_items
         JOIN JSON_TABLE(
        products,
        '$.*' COLUMNS (
            quantity VARCHAR(50) PATH '$'
            )
    ) j
WHERE `order_items`.`customer_id` = '01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KL';
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/reewoqUCQxeDLJb6zpb1RG/1):
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/reewoqUCQxeDLJb6zpb1RG/1

Could someone help me out here? Is this even possible?
Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you prefer to use JSON for this? Given that you know it's easier if you use normal rows and columns?

Comment: I don't want to change clients code that much for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to get the corresponding net_price and tax_price. I am not sure how you want to use them.

```
SELECT j.productId,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(i.products, CONCAT('$."', j.productId, '"'))) AS quantity,
  p.net_price,
  p.tax_price
FROM order_items AS i
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(i.products),
    '$[*]' COLUMNS (
        productId VARCHAR(26) PATH '$'
    )
) AS j
JOIN product AS p USING (productId)
WHERE i.`customer_id` = '01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KL';
```

Output given your sample data:

```
+----------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| productId                  | quantity | net_price | tax_price |
+----------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| 01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KH | 30       |       100 |        20 |
| 01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KH | 30       |       100 |        20 |
| 01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KH | 10       |       100 |        20 |
| 01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KK | 20       |       200 |        10 |
+----------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

---

Calculating the total aggregate price:

```
SELECT SUM(
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(i.products, CONCAT('$."', j.productId, '"')))
    * (p.net_price + p.tax_price)
  ) AS total_price
FROM order_items AS i
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(i.products),
    '$[*]' COLUMNS (
        productId VARCHAR(26) PATH '$'
    )
) AS j
JOIN product AS p USING (productId)
WHERE i.`customer_id` = '01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KL';
```

Output:

```
+-------------+
| total_price |
+-------------+
|       12600 |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. This is very near.
At least, I would like to get the total price as one single integer value.
sth. like that SUM(quantity * net_price + quantity * tax_price )

Comment: Any idea what this is? Both tables using utf8mb4_unicode_ci. (percona 8.0)

[HY000][1267] Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: I can't reproduce the error in my environment. I'd guess your `collation_connection` is set to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci. You can either `SET NAMES utf8mb4 OLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;` or you can override the implicit collation: `... WHERE i.customer_id = '01G51A4EK52RHB361SMXH2D5KL' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I figured it out with your help. By default the Jetbrains IDE used the default collation of the mysql driver. This makes sense. To change that: Open DB Settings, go to advanced tab. Search for "connectionCollation" and enter your collation. For me it was "utf8mb4_unicode_ci". Was just an IDE problem.