# mysql 5.7.12 json extract sum

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, metabase, mysql-json

I need the sum of the "total" value. But my query always returns **0**

My json field:

```
{'damage_budget': [{"id": 1, "name": "test-one", "value": 131, "quantity": 1}, {"id": 10, "name": "test-two", "value": 460, "quantity": 1}]}
```

My query:

`select id, sum(column ->>'$.damage_budget[*].value') from table`

Comment: Where *exactly* does `damage_budget` come from? It doesn't appear at all in the field value you've provided.

Comment: {'damage_budget': [{"id": 1, "name": "test-one", "value": 131, "quantity": 1}, {"id": 10, "name": "test-two", "value": 460, "quantity": 1}]}

Comment: Code and pertinent data doesn't belong down here in the comments; can you edit your question to include this data if that's *actually* what you're working with?

Comment: Yes, I can. Sorry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Labs JSON native type: How SUM the result of an array returned by jsn\_extract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731513/mysql-labs-json-native-type-how-sum-the-result-of-an-array-returned-by-jsn-extr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your extract returns a JSON array, not a scalar.

```
mysql> set @j = '{"damage_budget": [{"id": 1, "name": "test-one", "value": 131, "quantity": 1}, {"id": 10, "name": "test-two", "value": 460, "quantity": 1}]}';
mysql> select json_unquote(json_extract(@j, '$.damage_budget[*].value')) as v;
+------------+
| v          |
+------------+
| [131, 460] |
+------------+
```

The argument to `SUM()` must be a scalar.

There's no simple way to do a SUM() against a JSON array in MySQL 5.7. Solutions exist, but they involve coding complex procedures.

You should either upgrade to MySQL 8.0 so you can use JSON_TABLE() (for example see my answer to [MySql join by json key and multiply quantity for each order item and get total price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72549121/mysql-join-by-json-key-and-multiply-quantity-for-each-order-item-and-get-total-p/72549346#72549346)), or else store your data in normal rows and columns, not JSON.

In fact, there's no reason to store the data you show in JSON regardless of which version of MySQL you use. You should just store it in normal rows and columns.